# Reading .mpr/.mps/.mpt files with pd.read_csv

Tags: dataframe, csv

I'm trying to read some .mpr, .mps and .mpt files with Pandas and my professor told us to use pd.read_csv to open them. When I try to do this using: pd.read_csv(path+filename, delimiter='\t', header=55) I get the following error consistently:

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 9, saw 2

If I use skip_rows I can circumvent this problem and display the column names of the file, but no data appears. I know the file isn't empty so I'm wondering why this is happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong how you give him the path.
I just tried it with an .mpt file not the others, but the easiest way could be like this:

```
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

data_path = pathlib.Path(r'C:\Users\username\FolderName\filename.mpt')
df = pd.read_csv(data_path)
```